# How to make the fixed side bar like reddit website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reddit

I have already tried with fixed and sticky position.Let's say we have two columns in our website, main column and sidebar.And our side column has contents longer than the height of the view port( like in [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/) website as it contains footer and some ads).With fixed position , side bar doesn't scroll on page scroll.With sticky position , the side bar is initially sticky and scrolls only when the main column is ending. In reddit side bar , the right side bar scrolls along with page scroll. When the sidebar reaches the end of its content , it becomes sticky to the view port. How can i achieve that?

Here is the code for css

```
.sidenav {   position: sticky;   top: 20px;    right: 0;   left: 0;   float: left;   padding:10px;   z-index:999998; }

.sidenav a {
    padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #2196F3;
    display: block; }

.main {
    margin-left: 140px; 
    font-size: 28px; 
    padding: 0px 10px; }
```

code for html

```
<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#services">Services</a>
  <a href="#clients">Clients</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac nisi nec mi elementum pretium sit amet ac leo. Vestibulum pellentesque, nisl sed bibendum mollis, neque quam auctor lorem, a mollis erat risus id purus. Etiam vel semper nibh. Praesent ac augue ultricies, auctor orci sed, mollis metus. Nunc in tempus lectus. Duis id sapien dignissim, lobortis velit ornare, fringilla ex.
    <p>
</div>
```

Comment: When you're using fixed position means it's not following any rules from its parents. that's something you need to keep in mind, plus `sticky` position is still very tricky to use if you're targeting browsers either than Chrome. https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

Comment: Why don't you look into their code and sort it out from there?

Comment: The link you directed us to has no fixed sidebar whatsoever - it all scrolls

Answer (score 1):

Edited:

HTML:

```html
<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#services">Services</a>
  <a href="#clients">Clients</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <div class="sticky-tag">
  <a href="#sticky">sticky</a>
  <a href="#sticky">sticky</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac nisi nec mi elementum pretium sit amet ac leo. Vestibulum pellentesque, nisl sed bibendum mollis, neque quam auctor lorem, a mollis erat risus id purus. Etiam vel semper nibh. Praesent ac augue ultricies, auctor orci sed, mollis metus. Nunc in tempus lectus. Duis id sapien dignissim, lobortis velit ornare, fringilla ex.
    <br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac nisi nec mi elementum pretium sit amet ac leo. Vestibulum pellentesque, nisl sed bibendum mollis, neque quam auctor lorem, a mollis erat risus id purus. Etiam vel semper nibh.
    <br>Vestibulum pellentesque, nisl sed bibendum mollis, neque quam auctor lorem, a mollis erat risus id purus. Etiam vel semper nibh. Praesent ac augue ultricies, auctor orci sed, mollis metus. Nunc in tempus lectus. Duis id sapien dignissim, lobortis velit ornare, fringilla ex.<br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac nisi nec mi elementum pretium sit amet ac leo. Vestibulum pellentesque, nisl sed bibendum mollis, neque quam auctor lorem, a mollis erat risus id purus. Etiam vel semper nibh.
    <br>Vestibulum pellentesque, nisl sed bibendum mollis, neque quam auctor lorem, a mollis erat risus id purus. Etiam vel semper nibh. Praesent ac augue ultricies, auctor orci sed, mollis metus. Nunc in tempus lectus. Duis id sapien dignissim, lobortis velit ornare, fringilla ex.<br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac nisi nec mi elementum pretium sit amet ac leo. Vestibulum pellentesque, nisl sed bibendum mollis, neque quam auctor lorem, a mollis erat risus id purus. Etiam vel semper nibh.
    <br>Vestibulum pellentesque, nisl sed bibendum mollis, neque quam auctor lorem, a mollis erat risus id purus. Etiam vel semper nibh. Praesent ac augue ultricies, auctor orci sed, mollis metus. Nunc in tempus lectus. Duis id sapien dignissim, lobortis velit ornare, fringilla ex.<br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac nisi nec mi elementum pretium sit amet ac leo. Vestibulum pellentesque, nisl sed bibendum mollis, neque quam auctor lorem, a mollis erat risus id purus. Etiam vel semper nibh.
    <br>Vestibulum pellentesque, nisl sed bibendum mollis, neque quam auctor lorem, a mollis erat risus id purus. Etiam vel semper nibh. Praesent ac augue ultricies, auctor orci sed, mollis metus. Nunc in tempus lectus. Duis id sapien dignissim, lobortis velit ornare, fringilla ex.<br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac nisi nec mi elementum pretium sit amet ac leo. Vestibulum pellentesque, nisl sed bibendum mollis, neque quam auctor lorem, a mollis erat risus id purus. Etiam vel semper nibh.
    <br>Vestibulum pellentesque, nisl sed bibendum mollis, neque quam auctor lorem, a mollis erat risus id purus. Etiam vel semper nibh. Praesent ac augue ultricies, auctor orci sed, mollis metus. Nunc in tempus lectus. Duis id sapien dignissim, lobortis velit ornare, fringilla ex.<br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac nisi nec mi elementum pretium sit amet ac leo. Vestibulum pellentesque, nisl sed bibendum mollis, neque quam auctor lorem, a mollis erat risus id purus. Etiam vel semper nibh.
    <br>Vestibulum pellentesque, nisl sed bibendum mollis, neque quam auctor lorem, a mollis erat risus id purus. Etiam vel semper nibh. Praesent ac augue ultricies, auctor orci sed, mollis metus. Nunc in tempus lectus. Duis id sapien dignissim, lobortis velit ornare, fringilla ex.<br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac nisi nec mi elementum pretium sit amet ac leo. Vestibulum pellentesque, nisl sed bibendum mollis, neque quam auctor lorem, a mollis erat risus id purus. Etiam vel semper nibh.
    <br>Vestibulum pellentesque, nisl sed bibendum mollis, neque quam auctor lorem, a mollis erat risus id purus. Etiam vel semper nibh. Praesent ac augue ultricies, auctor orci sed, mollis metus. Nunc in tempus lectus. Duis id sapien dignissim, lobortis velit ornare, fringilla ex.<br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac nisi nec mi elementum pretium sit amet ac leo. Vestibulum pellentesque, nisl sed bibendum mollis, neque quam auctor lorem, a mollis erat risus id purus. Etiam vel semper nibh.
    <br>Vestibulum pellentesque, nisl sed bibendum mollis, neque quam auctor lorem, a mollis erat risus id purus. Etiam vel semper nibh. Praesent ac augue ultricies, auctor orci sed, mollis metus. Nunc in tempus lectus. Duis id sapien dignissim, lobortis velit ornare, fringilla ex.
    <p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.sidenav {
  margin-top: 20px;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 999998;
  width: 12%;
  height: 100vh; 
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #2196F3;
  display: block; 
}

.sidenav .sticky-tag {
  position: sticky;
  top: 20px;
}

.main {
  width: 88%;
  margin-left: 12%;
  font-size: 28px; 
  padding: 0px 15px; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention.But that doesn't scroll.

Comment: It should scroll, unless your content isn’t long enough than the screen height.

Comment: You could try to apply it on codepen for a quick prototype.

Comment: Sorry, I was missing height property in sidenav.Yes, it scrolls.But it doesn't scroll automatically with the main column.The page has now two scrollable column.

Comment: Updated with the similar version of reddit, sort of similar to the right ads column, am I correct?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But, sticky-tag doesn't stay sticky and it scrolls along with the sidenav column.

Answer (score 1):

You can store a specific scroll position value ( number of pixels) on the page at which you'd like to switch from the static scroll bar positioning over to fixing it to the bottom of the page. I used the start of the sidebar + the height of the sidebar - the window height + the padding I want below the sidebar. Then you just check the scroll position of the window when the document is scrolled and if it is past the value you stored, you add a class that switches its position to fixed. This snippet uses jQuery to accomplish the behavior in just a few lines.

```js
const sidebar = $('.sidebar');
const fixedScrollPosition = sidebar.offset().top + sidebar.outerHeight() - $(window).innerHeight() + 10;

$(document).on('scroll', function() {
  sidebar.toggleClass('fixed', $(window).scrollTop() > fixedScrollPosition);
});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p {
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}

p:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

.page-content {
  width: calc( 100% - 160px);
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: initial;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 150px;
  font-size: initial;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
}

.sidebar.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-content">
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</div>
<div class="sidebar">
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.I'm going to try your answer.